# Team showcase Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I have problem. I don't know how do that Team showcase slider -

> [![img][1]][1] in Wordpress, any idea? 
>   I can buy plugin, but how edit to look as image

Now I use slick slider, but I must have simply add person by plugin, not manual.

My slide:

```
<div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h1>Description</h1>

    <div class="col-3" style="background: url(obr.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
        <div class="bg-black">
            <hr>
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <p>Position</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `JPG !== GIF`. However, you can't start the animation of an animated gif when you want, you need to attach the image only when you need to start animation

Answer (score 0):

use jquery scroll event , i have created the code please find below

```
<div>
    <div style="display: none" id="loading">Loading..</div>
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <h1>Description</h1>

    <div class="col-3" style="background: url(obr.jpg) no-repeat; background-size: cover;"> <div class="bg-black"> <hr>
            <h1>Name</h1>
            <p>Position</p>
        </div> 
    </div>
</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $( "div#loading" ).css( "display", "block" ).hide(1000);
});
</script>
```